# Where is the documentation for all function/property($word->Documents->Open(), $excel->Visible... ) in COM PHP?

Tags: php, excel, com

As i checked on https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php#19688 page, i can see some examples of how to use COM object function but I don't know where to see the full documentation of these COM function? For example:

```
 <?php
   /***
    * Grouping Rows optically in Excel Using a COM Object
    *
    * That was not easy, I have spent several hours of trial and error to get
    * this thing to work!!!
    *
    * @author Kulikov Alexey <a.kulikov@gmail.com>
    * @since  13.03.2006
    *
    * @see    Open Excel, Hit Alt+F11, thne Hit F2 -- this is your COM bible
    ***/

   //starting excel
   $excel = new COM("excel.application") or die("Unable to instanciate excel");
   print "Loaded excel, version {$excel->Version}\n";

   //bring it to front
   #$excel->Visible = 1;//NOT

   //dont want alerts ... run silent
   $excel->DisplayAlerts = 0;

   //create a new workbook
   $wkb = $excel->Workbooks->Add();

   //select the default sheet
   $sheet=$wkb->Worksheets(1);

   //make it the active sheet
   $sheet->activate;

   //fill it with some bogus data
   for($row=1;$row<=7;$row++){
       for ($col=1;$col<=5;$col++){

          $sheet->activate;
          $cell=$sheet->Cells($row,$col);
          $cell->Activate;
          $cell->value = 'pool4tool 4eva ' . $row . ' ' . $col . ' ak';
       }//end of colcount for loop
   }

   ///////////
   // Select Rows 2 to 5
   $r = $sheet->Range("2:5")->Rows;

   // group them baby, yeah
   $r->Cells->Group;

   // save the new file
   $strPath = 'tfile.xls';
   if (file_exists($strPath)) {unlink($strPath);}
   $wkb->SaveAs($strPath);

   //close the book
   $wkb->Close(false);
   $excel->Workbooks->Close();

   //free up the RAM
   unset($sheet);

   //closing excel
   $excel->Quit();

   //free the object
   $excel = null;
?>
```

In the script above, I can not find documentation for Visible, DisplayAlerts, Worksheets, activate, SaveAs, Workbooks->Add().... property, function in php website

Thank in advance

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, you're using Word or Excel COM "object models", for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts

Answer (score 0):

The [Excel object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model) is described in MSDN.

Be aware that Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

If you deal with open XML documents only you may consider using the Open XML SDK, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.